# httpwatch automation code doesn't work in IE6

Tags: c#, testing, automation, httpwatch

```
        Controller con = new Controller();
        Plugin plugin = null;

        try
        {
            plugin = con.New();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

my code running fine in IE8. But same code does not work in a different machine with IE6. I would request you to please see this screenshot[alt text http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/6278/httpwatch.png](http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/6278/httpwatch.png) for details. My hardware details is as below

OS: Windows Server 2003 SP2
Browser: IE6
HttpWatch Version: 5.3.33 proff edition

When I try to run my code it just open a blank webpage and after few minutes it throws time out error. Also I want to add one more thing, if I open the a webpage first and start httpwatch and then if I run my programme it runs succesfully but only for one time. If I re-run my code once again it open a blank window again.

I have searched this problem in httpwatch blog and found that earlier it was a bug but it solved in 5.3.33 version. I will look forward your suggestions in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ask this problem to Httpwatch support guys and after lot of investigation we are able to solve this problem. I really want to thank simtec (who developed httpwatch) for their support.

The solution is very easy but it took a lot of time to figure it out, here it is: Go to IE>Internet Option> Advanced> Enable Third party browser extension.

Thanks,
Pritam